# Apex Sharing Assertion Failure

Tags: apex

noticing some odd behavior on this test I wrote. Seems really strange but when I do this assert by itself it fails:

```
    List<String> newGmSharedSnapshots = new List<String>();
    for(CS_Contract_Snapshot__Share share: newGmShares) {
        newGmSharedSnapshots.add(share.ParentId);
        system.assert(newGmSharedSnapshots.contains(share.ParentId))

    }
```

However, when I add this debug log prior to assertion, the test passes:

```
    List<String> newGmSharedSnapshots = new List<String>();
    for(CS_Contract_Snapshot__Share share: newGmShares) {
        newGmSharedSnapshots.add(share.ParentId);
        system.debug('Share Parent ID List: '+newGmSharedSnapshots)
        system.assert(newGmSharedSnapshots.contains(share.ParentId))
    }
```

really strange - just looking for some ideas.

Comment: With just what you have, this code should not compile; share is outside the scope of the for loop it is defined in. Even so, this may a variation of a bug where this happens with ID values.

Comment: Does this even compile? You won't be able to access `share` outside the loop.

Comment: I made an edit to include the assertion in the loop - it does compile

Comment: Pretty sure this question is a duplicate but having trouble finding the original.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you link to reported bug that you described? I'm curious if other people reported similar things

Comment: This [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AT9cQAG) might be it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's one I was thinking of. There was a similar one with `Set<Id>`, too, I think.